# What is the average area of the squares in a $15000$m dotted grid where each dot is $1$m away

Tags: summation

> What is the average area of the squares in a 15000m dotted grid where each dot is 1m away

I've been struggling with this question because of two things :
First, I can't think of a way to calculate the area of oblique squares (although I can count them).
Secondly, the calculations are quite a mess because of the number of sum of squares involved. And the solution in the book goes over calculations very fast so I got a little bit off. Therefore, if someone is feeling generous with their time, I would appreciate a more understandable solution.

Comment: 1. Is the grid square with 15000 dots on each side? [i.e. the dots are on the sides of the square] 2. Are you to count *all* squares which can be made with the dots [even those making various angles with the sides of the big square]? 3. Is there an answer for the count which you're trying to verify? [If so please include/]

Comment: As to $2$, I'm pretty sure that's what's meant by "oblique squares."  As to $1$, my guess is that each side of the square has $15001$ dots, so that the entire square is $15000$ m on each side.

Comment: 1. There are $15001$ dots
2. Yes all squares, this is what makes the question hard
3. The answer is approximately 30m squared (30,004006)

Comment: It would be good to include the name and author of the book your problem comes from, and what pages it appears on [and edition if relevant]. If the solution doesn't take too much space, maybe a link to the solution would also be good.

Answer (score 0):

The areas for the oblique squares have a simple expression in terms of a "bounding square" which is $m \times m$ and an "offset" $k.$ The bounding square of a particular oblique square is determined by drawing two vertical lines through the leftmost and rightmost vertices of the oblique square, and two horizontal lines through the lowest and highest vertices of the oblique square. The offset $k$ is the height of the leftmost vertex of the oblique square above the lower horizontal line making the bounding box. Note that we can include also the non-oblique squares by taking the offset as zero.

To see this as a diagram place the lower left corner of the bounding box at the origin. Then using offset $k$ the four points of the (typically) oblique square are
$$ (0,k),\ \ (k,m),\ \ (m,m-k),\ \ (m-k,0). $$
Then the area of this oblique square is $k^2+(m-k)^2.$ there are exactly $(n-m+1)^2$ bounding squares which are $m \times m.$ Using known formulas for sums of powers and some algebra, and also the total number of oblique and non-oblique squares in the large $n \times n$ grid, the average area of the two types of squares in the grid, oblique and non-oblique, can be expressed as
$$ \frac{2n^2+4n+9}{15}.$$ Note that in my setup there are in fact $n+1$ lattice points on each side of the large square. This is to make the actual dimensions $n \times n.$